# Eliminar o Reset elementos de un select en JQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Estoy haciendo un select que se llene de acuerdo a la información que se haya solicitado con la solicitud ajax, pero cuando vuelvo hacer otra petición ajax, el select conserva los elementos de la anterior solicitud
Anexo el codigo:

```
jQuery("#student-list").on('click', '.add-auxiliar', function(){

        var codigo_guia = jQuery(this).data("studentid");

        var action = 'fetch_auxiliar';

        jQuery('.modal-title').html("Asignar Auxiliar");

        jQuery.ajax({

            url:'accion.php',

            method:"POST",

            data:{codigo_guia:codigo_guia, action:action},

            dataType:"json",

            success:function(json){
                jQuery('#asignar-auxiliar').modal('show');
        
                    if(json == null){
                         $("#select_auxiliar").append('<option>Ya cuenta con una auxiliar asignada</option>');

                    }else{
                         jQuery('#codigo-guia').val(codigo_guia);
            jQuery('#action-aux').val('asignar_aux');

$.each(json,function(i, value){
   $("#select_auxiliar").append('<option value="'+value.codigo_es+'">'+value.Nombre+'</option>');
   
});
        $("#select_auxiliar").append('<option value="Reset">Reset</option>');
                    }
                     
                
                
                  
              
                    }

        })

    });
```

Entonces estoy buscando una forma de eliminar los "append" que ya se agregaron cuando se vuelva abrir el modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la función de javascript `empty()` de este modo:

```javascript
$("#select_auxiliar").empty();
```

En tu caso, ponla justo antes del condicional, así:

```javascript
jQuery("#student-list").on('click', '.add-auxiliar', function() {
console.log("llego");
  var codigo_guia = jQuery(this).data("studentid");
  var action = 'fetch_auxiliar';
  jQuery('.modal-title').html("Asignar Auxiliar");
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'accion.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      codigo_guia: codigo_guia,
      action: action
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
      jQuery('#asignar-auxiliar').modal('show');

      $("#select_auxiliar").empty();

      if (json == null) {
        $("#select_auxiliar").append('<option>Ya cuenta con una auxiliar asignada</option>');
      } else {
        jQuery('#codigo-guia').val(codigo_guia);
        jQuery('#action-aux').val('asignar_aux');
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
          $("#select_auxiliar").append('<option value="' + value.codigo_es + '">' + value.Nombre + '</option>');
        });
        $("#select_auxiliar").append('<option value="Reset">Reset</option>');
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Encontrarás más información en su [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/empty/#empty)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió :D